# How this ksh code is working?

Tags: linux, redirect, stdout, ksh, aix

```
echo "Hello" > $XYZ

echo ${?}
```

If I copy paste those two lines in any .sh file the scripts are working fine without any issues. `${?}` in the second line is returning 0. `$XYZ` can be replaced with any random string. The variable need not be defined or initialized.

However, the same code is not working for some users. The first line is throwing the error "`scriptname.sh[425]: : cannot open`".

`${?}` in the second line is returning 1.

Any idea on why the same piece of code is giving different results for different users?

**Note:** We are facing this issue in the server **"IBM/AIX RISC System/6000"**

Comment: There is no such thing as "Linux code". Do you mean Bash? Or what?

Comment: So this is a ksh programming question. Please amend title and tags accordingly. Thanks

Comment: I have now corrected the title. But, I am still not getting the answer to my question. How the Korn shell is executing the line without throwing any error message?

Comment: Could different users have different shells? Does the script specifically have `#!/bin/ksh` as its first line?

Comment: No. All the users have the same shell. The first line of the script is  `#!/bin/ksh`

Answer (score 0):

The variable XYZ needs to hold a non-empty string in order for the shell to be able to parse the redirection. Maybe initialize it to `/dev/null` if you want it to default to no result at all (which is what I imagine you might expect a redirection to nothing to accomplish; but it doesn't).

Comment: Just now I tested by executing the below commands and all ran fine without any error.

    echo "Test" > $XROELRLER
    echo "Test" > $EROOTRTUEROOOROEOREOREORO
    echo "Test" > $OOEREMREOEREREOR
    echo "Test" > /dev/null

None of the above variables are defined any where. They are all just random names.

However, I noticed that for the first 3 lines above "Test" is being printed in the terminal, but for the 4 lines where I used /dev/null the string "Test" is not being printed.

Is there any Linux setting that will ignore the file redirects if the variables are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to write the assignment statement of XYZ in the correct form. e.g:

```
XYZ="fileName"
echo "Hello" > $XYZ
...
```

XYZ="fileName" is without spaces.. I don't know but this is the only issue that came to my mind

Comment: I understand, but my question is different. The OS is not throwing any error if I execute the command "echo "Hello" > $RANDOM_STRING". Here, $RANDOM_STRING is undefined random variable. I wanted to understand how this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagining the log file ($XYZ) is not accessible to different users in AIX, try giving 755 to log file directory and also make sure your file having enough permissions to get executed by others (755 again)

Comment: $XYZ is a random undefined variable. I can replace $XYZ with any random value ($XEREOER, $DOREORLR, $EROEROERO etc). The script is working. I want to understand why the OS is not throwing the error. What Linux setting is supressing the error?

Comment: I would say you should generic way of using logging techniques by defining it log name in string ..